# Should I use always requestFocusInWindow() instead of requestFocus()?

Tags: java, macos, swing, focus

I read that `requestFocus()` sometimes fails because it's platform-based.

The general rule of thumb is to always use `requestFocusInWindow()` ?

By the way, my app is developed solely for macOS.

Comment: *"By the way, my app is developed solely for macOS"* - Shouldn't make any difference, the JavaDocs clearly recommend `requestFocusInWindow` over `requestFocus`, regardless of the reasons why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read that requestFocus() sometimes fails because it's
>   platform-based.

Yes. This is correct. [From Java Docs the `requestFocus()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow())

> Note that the use of this method is discouraged because its behavior
>   is **platform dependent**. Instead we recommend the use of
>   requestFocusInWindow(boolean).

Because of the **plataform dependent** is not recommended you will build in Linux and will not run as expected in Windows.

```
requestFocusInWindow()
```

> The focus behavior of this method can be **implemented uniformly across**
>   **platforms**, and thus developers are strongly encouraged to use this
>   method over requestFocus when possible. Code which relies on
>   requestFocus may exhibit different focus behavior on different
>   platforms.

*Should I use always requestFocusInWindow() instead of requestFocus()?*

It depends. If you want to your app runs only in specific OS use `requestFocus()` if you want to be multiplataform use     `requestFocusInWindow()`

When in doubt always go for the documentantion.